# How to sign on office documents with sha256/384/512 using PackageDigitalSignatureManager on .Net framework 3.0

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, openxml, digital-signature, sha

I'm trying to programmatically sign an office document(Word\Excel) on a signature line provider using PackageDigitalSignatureManager class but I got an Unsupported hash algorithm exception:

```
General exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unsupported hash algorithm specified.   
at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.XmlDigitalSignatureProcessor.Sign(IEnumerable`1 parts, IEnumerable`1 relationshipSelectors, X509Certificate2 signer, String signatureId, Boolean embedCertificate, IEnumerable`1 signatureObjects, IEnumerable`1 objectReferences)    
at System.IO.Packaging.PackageDigitalSignatureManager.Sign(IEnumerable`1 parts, X509Certificate certificate, IEnumerable`1 relationshipSelectors, String signatureId, IEnumerable`1 signatureObjects, IEnumerable`1 objectReferences)
```

Here is a part of my code:

```
string SigInfoHashAlg = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
string HashAlg = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";

PackageDigitalSignatureManager dsm = new PackageDigitalSignatureManager(package);
dsm.CertificateOption = CertificateEmbeddingOption.InSignaturePart;
dsm.HashAlgorithm = SigInfoHashAlg;
System.Collections.Generic.List<Uri> toSign = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Uri>();
System.Collections.Generic.List<PackageRelationshipSelector> relationshipSelectors = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PackageRelationshipSelector>();
foreach (PackageRelationship relationship in package.GetRelationshipsByType("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument"))
{
  AddSignableItems(relationship, toSign, relationshipSelectors);
}

X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(Cert);
System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.DataObject> signatureObjects = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.DataObject>();
System.Collections.Generic.List<Reference> objectReferences = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Reference>();
Reference officeItemRef = new Reference(_OfficeUri);
officeItemRef.Type = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#Object";
try{
    NewSig = dsm.Sign(toSign, cert, relationshipSelectors, "idPackageSignature", signatureObjects, objectReferences);
}
catch (CryptographicException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

I have searched and found lots of pages using the PackageDigitalSignatureManager class but none of them gives a working example or explanation about this procedure.

As I understood from my research the dsm.HashAlgorithm should be the parameter that affects the signing algorithm (Saw it even in the source code of the .Net framework XmlDigitalSignatureProcessor).

I know someone will think that the SignatureDescription class will be a solution but I have tried this as well.

1. I have configured the machine.config to work with my relevant hash IDs
2. SHA1 is working properly and till now the SHA1 was kind of hard coded. If you'll need any other information, you are welcome to ask for it.
3. Pay attention I'm talking about Net Framework 3.0 so 4.0 solutions are not relevant unless you will say that there is no other choice(Last resort).

Thank you very very much,
Alex.